# Why Windows 7 dialog fonts are not anti-aliased?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, anti-aliasing

[image]

As you can see my Windows 7 dialog fonts are not anti-aliased, but other fonts are ok. How can I get the anti-aliased fonts back?

Answer (score 10):

Make sure both ClearType and smooth edges on fonts (anti-aliasing) are on. Microsoft makes this super confusing by putting the two settings if two very different and hard-to-find places. But Start Menu search rules the world and if you know what to search for...!

For ClearType go to the Start Menu and type "Adjust ClearType text": enable "Turn on ClearType". Or from Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Adjust ClearType text > enable **"Turn on CrearType"**.

For smooth edges go to the Start Menu and type "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows" or from Computer > System Properties > Windows Experience Index (link) > [shield] Adjust visual effects (left sidebar) > enable **"Smooth edges of screen fonts"** (4th from bottom).

Comment: Thanks! It turns out that the reason my fonts were badly aliased was because of my graphics card settings. For some reason my graphics card was outputting the screen at a much smaller resolution than the monitor was showing, and then it was allowing the monitor to enlarge/scale the input to fit the screen. This was creating horrible aliased text and weird distortion when viewing motion. I'm posting this in case it's useful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the font used in the dialog contains bitmap characters. This situation is the same for CJK fonts which often contains bitmap for small size characters, so no font anti-aliasing could be applied when rendering except for large size text.