# How to enable font anti aliasing in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Windows 7 dialog fonts are not anti-aliased?](https://superuser.com/questions/341636/why-windows-7-dialog-fonts-are-not-anti-aliased)

suddenly my dialog fonts turned non anti aliased and looks ugly... I want to make them anti-aliased again how can I do this?

please help

Comment: Closed as a *very* close duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Check if ClearType is still enabled:

Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → Display → Adjust ClearType text

Then check your font settings for windows, menu items and dialog boxes:

Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → Personalization → Window Color → Advanced appearance settings